# Inject dependency to the angularjs directive using typescript

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

Lets say I have a simple angular directive that looks like this:

```
app.directive('setFocus', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    link: function(_scope, _element) {
        $timeout(function() {
            _element[0].focus();
        }, 0);
    }
};
}]);
```

How can I write this using Typescript and get the $timeout accesible within the link function? My example would look something like this:

```
/// <reference path="../../reference.ts"/>

class SetFocus{
    constructor() {
        var directive: ng.IDirective = {};
        directive.restrict = 'EA';
        directive.scope = { };        
        directive.link= function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        // How can I access $timeout here?

        }
        return directive;
    }
}

directives.directive('setFocus', [SetFocus]);
```

This might be a silly example but it is the principle I would like to get working, which is using injected dependencies in the angular link function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this way:

```
class SetFocus implements ng.IDirective {
    //Directive settings
    restrict :string = 'EA';
    scope : any= {};
    //Take timeout argument in the constructor
    constructor(private $timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {
    }

    link: ng.IDirectiveLinkFn = ($scope: ng.IScope, $element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, $attrs: ng.IAttributes) => {
          //refer to the timeout
          this.$timeout(function() {
            $element[0].focus();
         }, 0);
    }
    //Expose a static func so that it can be used to register directive.
    static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
       //Create factory function which when invoked with dependencies by
       //angular will return newed up instance passing the timeout argument
        var directive: ng.IDirectiveFactory = 
              ($timeout:ng.ITimeoutService) => new SetFocus($timeout);
        //directive's injection list
        directive.$inject = ["$timeout"];
        return directive;
    }
}

directives.directive('setFocus', SetFocus.factory());
```

It could be a problem with the way you have it right now. Because directive factory is not newed up so its constructor will execute with `this` as global object. This way you don't end up having a huge constructor as well and can write it in proper class *ey* manner.

If you have many dependencies injected instead of repeating the arguments in the factory you could as well do:

```
  var directive: ng.IDirectiveFactory =
            (...args) => new (SetFocus.bind.apply(SetFocus, [null].concat(args)));
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid all the factory boilerplate (and the constructor array at all), I recently wrote a small library (currently as a test project), that make the definition of directives very simple (controller and template omitted here):

```
@Directive('userRank')
export class UserRankDirective implements ng.IDirective {

    controller = UserRankDirectiveController;
    restrict = 'A';
    template = template;
    //controllerAs: 'ctrl', set as default
    replace = true;
    scope = {
        user: '=userRank'
    }

    constructor($q: ng.IQService) {
        console.log('Q service in UserRankDirective:', $q);
    }

}
```

It uses decorators like `@Directive` and a customized version of the TypeScript compiler that make interfaces metadata available at runtime (so `ng.IQService` can be translated to `'$q'` and injected in the constructor array). 
No more `app.directive(...)` boilerplate: everything is done in decorators :)
You can give a look at the sample application code [here](https://github.com/pcan/angular-ts-test)