# Angular directive this undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why am I getting and `undefined` when I console out `this` in this Angular directive?

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function ExampleDirective() {
    var self = this;

    // returns undefined
    console.log(self);

    return {};
  }

  angular
    .module('example')
    .directive('exampleDirective', ExampleDirective);

})();
```

Comment: 1st place why you want to use this in controller link function..you need to use `controller` with `controllerAs` option

Comment: it is simply because directive factory does not get _new_ ed up. So in strict mode `this` will be undefined in non strict mode _this_ will be global window

Answer (score 2):

It is simply because directive factory does not get newed up (instantiated ). So in **[`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)** `this` will be undefined in `non strict` mode `this` will be global window which you do not want to pollute as well.

However if you really want to write it that way you would need to new up and return the instance yourself when directive factory is provided.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  //Accept any dependencies here
  function ExampleDirective($timeout) {
    var self = this;

    // returns undefined
    console.log(self);

    this.restrict = 'AE';
    this.templateUrl = "MyTemplate.html";
    this.link = function(scope, elm, attrs){

    }
  }

   ExampleDirective.factory = function () {
    //Create factory function which when invoked
    //angular will return newed up instance passing the timeout argument
    var directive = function ($timeout) { return new ExampleDirective($timeout); };
    //directive's injection list
    directive.$inject = ['$timeout'];
    return directive;
  };

  angular
    .module('example')
    .directive('exampleDirective', ExampleDirective.factory());

})();
```

This probably is an overkill though you can use this technique when writing [directives in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878157/inject-dependency-to-the-angularjs-directive-using-typescript/30878266#30878266). As mentioned in the [comment by @pankajparkar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035275/angular-directive-this-undefined#comment50094865_31035275) You could use a controller and associate it to the directive. Controllers gets instantiated (newed up) and `this` will point to the controller instance itself.