# angular 1.5 (components): how to use directives with es6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

in folder `directives` i created two files: `directives.js` and `color.js`

`directives` i've imported into app.js

**directives.js:**

```
import angular from 'angular';

import ColorDirective from './color';

const moduleName = 'app.directives';

angular.module(moduleName, [])

  .directive('color', ColorDirective);

export default moduleName;
```

**color.js**

```
import angular from 'angular';


let ColorDirective = function () {

  return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
      console.log('ColorDirective');
    }
  }

}

export default ColorDirective;
```

and on one element in component i've added `color` as attr.

But it's not working. I mean inner link loop. Why? What i have wrong coded? How to use directives with angular 1.5 & es2016 ?

Comment: maybe you just have to write `return response.data`? Depends on your returned rest object.

Comment: Simply return MyService.getData(), without the .then(....) part. uid-typehead expects a promise

Comment: I have not used resangular, so I'm not sure what it returns. Try adding the $q service to your controller, and return $q.resolve(response) instead of return response - this will return a promise that will resolve with response.

Comment: it would be nice to see the whole app somewhere on plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have written its not possible to see the problem. The code you provide works, assuming that you have included your module into the page and the code is correctly compiled.

I have put your code into a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/fccmxchx/

```
let ColorDirective = function () {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element) {
      console.log('ColorDirective');
      element.text('ColorDirective');
    }
  }
}

angular.module('app.directives', [])
  .directive('color', ColorDirective);
```

unfortunately I cannot split your code into modules, but that is what your code is trying to do

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with es6 syntax but here is the typescript's way I'm using:

```
class ColorDirective implements angular.IDirective {

    constructor() { }

    link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ngModelCtrl) {

    }

    /**
    * Instance creation
    */
    static getInstance(): angular.IDirectiveFactory {
        // deendency injection for directive
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30878157/inject-dependency-to-the-angularjs-directive-using-typescript
        let directive: angular.IDirectiveFactory = () => new ColorDirective();
        directive.$inject = [];
        return directive;
    }
}

angular
    .module('moduleName')
    .directive('color', ColorDirective.getInstance());
```

EDIT: after some research, I've found the es6 way to do the same thing as above:

```
import angular from 'angular';

class ColorDirective {

    constructor() {

    }

    link(scope, element) {
      console.log('ColorDirective');
    }

    static getInstance() {
        var directive = new ColorDirective();
    }
}

export default ColorDirective.getInstance();
```

Comment: but how to use it, with my structure? now it doesn't work